# StructureMap Plugins - easier way?

Tags: structuremap

Let's say you have an interface of IModel that takes a pair of generics ...

```
public interface IModel<TOne, TTwo>
{
     TOne ConvertToOne(TTwo two);
     TTwo ConvertToTwo(TOne one);
}
```

and a class that implements this

```
public class OneTwo : IModel<SomethingOne, SomethingTwo>
{
   SomethingOne ConvertToOne(SomethingTwo two)
   { //zomg! nothing exciting!
   }

   ...
}
```

Nothing overly fancy.  In my mapping configs, I have a list that looks kind of like this ...

```
For<IModel<SomethingOne, SomethingTwo>>().Use<OneTwo>();
For<IModel<SomeOne, SomeTwo>>().Use<AnotherClass>();
```

and so on.  Based on DRY, I feel like this is the hard way to do this (there's 7 of them now, soon to be 20 or so).  Anyway to do this "more better"?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this... it might work.

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.Scan(scan =>
    { 
        scan.AssemblyContainingType<Something>();
        scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IModel<,>));
    }
}
```